# Type mismatch when defining a variable of type null or undefined

Tags: typescript

On creating a new typescript project in VS2015 (Typescript ver 2.9.2 and Typescript.MSBuild 3.0), I am unable to defined a variable with null or undefined which is a real pain as I can't use nullable types.

```
function test() {
    let x: null;
    let y: undefined;
}
```

The code compiles fine, but there is a type expected IntelliSense warning from the Typescript Virtual Projects folder.

My tsconfig.json is configured with the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks":  false,
        "sourceMap": true, // Generates a corresponding sourcemap file
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "../Scripts/custom"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true, // use instead of watch, as supported on visual studio
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot",
        "bin",
        "obj"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on. I found the Typescript Virtual Projects often shows ghost errors.

Comment: It's underscoring both the null and undefined types in the let statement.